# Why does my PHP PDO Select in while not working with page limit? Also issue with Array in select

Tags: php, pdo

Why does hello not display to the screen, why is the while loop not executed?
Also I have an issue because the array $zipcodeA[$x] may contain random zip codes like 90564 80564 70564 88464 98754 but the database tman may contain info such as 90564 90564 90564 80564 70564 70564 88464 98754. How do I get the select to go through all the zip codes that are in the array $zipcodeA[$x] instead of just pulling info of one of each zip code?  The database holds random zip codes and many zip codes can be duplicates, the array only many different zip codes with no duplicates

```
for($x = 0; $x <= $v; $x++) 
{
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tman WHERE approve = 'Y' AND zip = :zipp ORDER BY id desc limit :limit");
$stmt->bindParam(":zipp", $zipcodeA[$x], PDO::PARAM_INT); 
$stmt->bindValue(':limit', (int) $limit, PDO::PARAM_INT); 
echo '<br>zipcode: ' . $zipcodeA[$x] . '<br>';
$stmt->execute();   
    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
      $id2 = $row['id'];
      $name = $row['name'];
      echo 'hello';

    } 
}
```

Comment: If your column is called `zip` try and make the binding name the same. Code where everything has a multitude of different aliases is really challenging to work with.

Comment: I did that but still it does not go into the while loop

Comment: Just one thought... **what's the value of `$v`?**

Comment: It's not clear from your question what sort of data you're operating on here, nor how many rows you're expecting to get. Could a [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) on `$zipcodeA` clear up this code?

Comment: The limit I set as 10, but could be any number. The database holds random zip codes and many zip codes can be duplicates, the array only many different zip codes with no duplicates

Comment: The value of $v is the number of zip codes in the array $zipcodeA[$x]. Could be any number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do it like this :

```
$limit = ($pageno - 1) * $rows_per_page . ',' . $rows_per_page; 
for($x = 0; $x <= $v; $x++) {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tman WHERE approve = 'Y' AND zip = :zipp ORDER BY id desc LIMIT " . $limit);
    $stmt->bindParam(":zipp", $zipcodeA[$x], PDO::PARAM_INT); 
    echo '<br>zipcode: ' . $zipcodeA[$x] . '<br>';
    $stmt->execute();   
    $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if (!empty($result)) {
        $id2 = $result['id'];
        $name = $result['name'];
        echo 'hello';
    }
}
```

Comment: When I removed this limit :limit  it worked. Just have to figure out what the issue is there

Comment: You already initialize your variable *$limit* ? If you already do it, I think it's not the problem.

Comment: This is the way I initialized it:   $limit = 'LIMIT ' .($pageno - 1) * $rows_per_page .',' .$rows_per_page;

Comment: ouch I see, can you try my answer again? I already updated it just now.

Comment: BTW, you have been wrong initialization.  $limit = (($pageno - 1) * $rows_per_page) . ',' . $rows_per_page;

Comment: You cannot do that in BindValue because your *$limit* is a string

Comment: Can you check your $pageno , $rows_per_page , and $rows_per_page is a right value?

Comment: ah, my bad, forgot to remove *intval*. You can do it again. I already update the answer.

Comment: I got this error  :    Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIMIT 0,100' at line 1'

Comment: Can you echo the SQL statement? because there is syntax error

Comment: Have you change your *$limit* to this : **$limit = ($pageno - 1) * $rows_per_page . ',' . $rows_per_page;** ?

Comment: Okay, glad if I can help you. Gud luck in your future development.

Comment: If you have new Question again, just tag me on the comment, may be I can help.

Answer (score 1):

### You should replace your limit parameter with a PHP variable:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tman
    WHERE approve='Y' AND zip=:zipp
    ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $limiter");
```

According to the PHP [PDO::prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) manual in regard to prepared statements:

> Use these parameters to bind ***any user-input***, do not include the
>   user-input directly in the query.

Since preparing a statement lets you filter user input, these parameters, by design are not allowed to replace any other part of the query that is supposed to be set by a developer. For instance allowing a parameter to replace a table name would provide access to an attacker to use the privileges of the user on anything the user has access to. Likewise, in your situation, [LIMIT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/limit-optimization.html) is provided through MySQL as a query optimization. Exploiting this feature can bring down a system where massive datasets exist.

Also you should wrap your PDO query with a [Try/Catch statement](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers#Error_Handling) to prevent others from seeing your PDO exceptions when they're thrown.

```
//Load your IP here
$dev_ip = 'your.ip.address.here';
//Filter the user's IP
$user_ip = filter_input(INPUT_SERVER,'REMOTE_ADDR', FILTER_VALIDATE_IP);
//Set your limiting variable
$limiter = ($pageno-1)*$rows_per_page.','.$rows_per_page; 
for($x = 0; $x <= $v; $x++) {
    try {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tman WHERE approve='Y' AND zip=:zipp ORDER BY id desc LIMIT $limiter");
    $stmt->bindParam(":zipp", $zipcodeA[$x], PDO::PARAM_INT); 
    if(array_key_exists($x, $zipcodeA)&&!empty($zipcodeA[$x])){
        echo '<br>zipcode: ' . $zipcodeA[$x] . '<br>';
        $stmt->execute();   
        $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if (array_key_exists('id', $result)&&!empty($result['id'])) {
            $id2 = $result['id'];
        } else {
            if($user_ip==$dev_ip){
             echo 'No ID';
            }
        }
        if (array_key_exists('name', $result)&&!empty($result['name'])) {
            $name = $result['name'];
        } else {
            if($user_ip==$dev_ip){
             echo 'No Name';
            }
        }
    }

    } catch(PDOException $ex) {
        echo "An Error occured!"; //user friendly message
        if($user_ip==$dev_ip){
         echo $ex->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't base your loop condition on the result of **fetch()**. Get the result and evaluate it separately.

From the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php): "The return value of this function on success depends on the fetch type." IE Not necc a great thing for a boolean evaluation. *It will* return false if it fails but when it succeeds it may behave in an unexpected manner.

Better - use **[fetchAll()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php)** and loop through the resultant array.

Last - check your result set using **print_r()**. Make sure you have something to loop through.